# how to put progress bar around map marker(car)

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, kotlin

[image]

I'm looking to make progress bar around google map marker like this image or how I would display a progress bar with a specific position on the map like I'm telling the latitude and longitude and displays with that position

Comment: You'd probably have to have multiple marker images and update the marker image per the progress value.

Comment: You think the progress is multiple of markers appear and disapears?

Comment: You can customize a marker's image.  You can also change the marker's image at any time.  Change it according to the progress with 1 of say 10 different marker images (0, 10%, 20%...).

Comment: can you show me a demo or links that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this short clip the progress marker (a series of 8 circles surrounding the marker) advances by one filled circle denoting progress - based on whatever progress calculation need (in this case 5 location updates but most likely would be distance complete).

The marker icon is the whole thing (car + plus marker pin + progress circles) and the icon is duplicated in 9 files with the progress circles changed.

I can post details if this is of interest but the summary is:

- Create as many marker images as there are progress states (9 in this example)
- Periodically update the progress by changing the marker icon corresponding to the progress (in 1/8 increments in this example)
- The flashing is accomplished using a handler delay and essentially toggles between icon0 (no circles filled) and current icon (based on progress calculation).
- the marker moves along with the location in this example by simply using `.setPosition()`.

Here's the handler implementation for the example provided:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 boolean onOff = false;
 @Override
 public void run() {
     // imageId is set in the onLocationChanged based on 'progress'
     // determination - 0/8 complete; 1/8 complete...
     int currentImageId = imageId;

     // icons is an array list populated at initialization with 
     // BitmapDescriptors from resources - one for each progress
     // fraction (0 - 8).
     BitmapDescriptor currentIcon = icons.get(currentImageId);

     // Flashing results from using the "0-progress" indicator icon
     // which is at index 0.
     BitmapDescriptor offIcon = icons.get(0);

     if (onOff) {
         marker1.setIcon(offIcon);
     } else {
         marker1.setIcon(currentIcon);
     }
     onOff = !onOff;

     // restart handler timer.
     handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
 }
}, 100);
```

Initialization of icons list is as follows:

```
// repeat for all progress images
final BitmapDescriptor icon0 = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car0);

// and add to list
final ArrayList<BitmapDescriptor> icons = new ArrayList<>();
// repeat for all progress images
icons.add(icon0);
```

The customization comes in the "progress determination" - if traveling along a route then in the `onLocationChanged` a path complete ratio is computed and applied to the max number of images to produce the above `imageId`.  Such as:

```
int imageId = pathCompleteRatio * maxImages;
```

Video
[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy, i understood the steps well and i did, only i need the toggling hundler, can you post in details this part of the code ?